# Only prints 1 instead of all arguments after converting to integer

Tags: c, integer

So how would I add str_to_int values to a[] (array)? So I can use a[] in another function, to get the mean.

Just ignore size. For size is just how many values are entered in command line.

```
./a.out 5 2 3
```

Which is 3.

Comment: `argv[1]` refers to only the first number passed in.  You'll want to  loop through the arguments, where `argc` is the number of arguments in the array.

Comment: @Serge like this? `for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++)` I am just struggling what I should put in the statement forloop.

Comment: Yes, something like that.  `printf("INT[]: "); int i; for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) { printf("%s ", argv[i]); } print("\n");`  Excuse me as c isn't my native tongue.

Answer (score 2):

You only pass `argv[1]`, which will be a single string containing `"4"` in your example. Not sure why you expect that to somehow step over the array `argv`.

Also, you can't legally have a function whose name starts with `str`, that space of names is reserved.

Answer (score 1):

you need to loop over argv:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int sum = 0;
  printf("INT[]: ");
  for (int i=1; i<argc; i++) {
    char *array = argv[i];
    sum += strToInt(array);
    printf("%s ", array);
  }
  printf("\n sum: %d\n",sum);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. Then, how would I add up all those values? Do I need to make global variable for sum of all integers?

Comment: you can use a local accumulator (int sum) to add the variable in the printing loop, updated the code to show how

Answer (score 0):

As other as mentioned, you need to loop over `argv`.Also, note that you call to `strToInt()` has unused result. Did you mean this?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
      printf("INT[]: ");
      int i, sum = 0;
      for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) 
      {
        char *array = argv[i];
        int n = strToInt(array);
        sum += n;
        printf("%d ", n);
      }
      printf("\n");
      printf("sum = %d", sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. Then, how would I add up all those values? Do I need to make global variable for sum of all integers? I have another function which is the mean value which takes the sum and n. I have n all sorted out by using while/for loop.

Comment: Another question, if I was to put int n outside the for loop, would it put all the integers in a array? I am trying to figure out for standard deviation.

Comment: You can declare `n` above loop (like `i` and `sum`) it will still works and give same result but is unnecessary since you don't need to `n` after end of loop is reached. You can replace `int n = ` by `sum += strToInt(array)` btw.

Comment: Then, how will the other function get access to n? I was thinking about creating a new variable int a[]; And put then in for loop, that way, after converting string to int, it will add to a[];. I did some research, int a[]; cannot have empty stack, which is weird. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to pass the sum of these values in the array to a function? isn't what `sum` value hold? you can use `n` anyway in the loop just do `f(n)`

Comment: Please check OP. I edited, so you can understand better. I think I will have to change the argument in str_to_int to char *array[]?